# How to put questions and score together in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to the programming world, I am having an issue with creating a code. I have written the basic but I would like to put a score and a number of questions for specific ages.

I have completed just the basics so far as I am new to this.

```
print ("Hi. Hope you are enjoying our App\n")
username = input("What's your name: ")
print ("Hello " + username + ". Welcome to MathzApp!\n")
age = int(input("What is your age," + username + "? "))
if age >= 9 and age <= 15:
    print("Hope you score the highest!\n")
else:
    print("I am sorry, you don't qualify for this quiz! \n")
print("FOR INFO ONLY!! \n" "You can answer up to 10 questions. \n")
nq = int(input("How many questions would you like to answer? "))
if nq >= 1 and nq <=5:
    print("Oh, I thought you would go big. Wish you luck! \n")
if nq >= 6 and nq <=10:
    print("Wish you the best. Answer the questions in your time! \n")
else:
    print("All the best. The value you inserted is invalid. Please return \n")
```

The code runs fine. I just would like an example of how can i input a score and ask them some questions. But I would like to have different questions for different ages. So let's say if they input 11, then they have questions just for 11 not any other ages, but they will also have a score at the end of the quiz. Any suggestions please?

Comment: I'd really recommend indenting your if statements, this is hard to read

Comment: ALso i would suggest simplifying chained comparison like so: `9 <= age <= 15`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is additional if statement.

And condition would look like:

```
if age == 11:
    # then do something
```

Read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp

Answer (score 0):

First you can separate you code in functions, if you want, this will be more readble, next about score how I understand you want to score user after each question, I mean if they answer for 3 question this score will be 3, so after each question put something like score_q = score_q + 1

Answer (score 0):

Please Learn the basics :

i think this is the one you are looking for

```
test_text = int(input ("Enter a number: "))
if test_text == 3 :
    print("how are you ")

elif test_text == 4:
    print("what is todays date")
```

end with elseif.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your questions in different lists, for example, you could have a list with the choices and correct answer:

```
# List of tuples: each item has question, options, answer in order
questions_for_11_yo = [
    ("THIS IS FIRST QUESTION", ("OPTION 1...", "OPTION 2...", "OPTION 3..."), 1),
    ("THIS IS SECOND QUESTION", ("OPTION 1...", "OPTION 2...", "OPTION 3..."), 2),
    ("THIS IS THIRD QUESTION", ("OPTION 1...", "OPTION 2...", "OPTION 3..."), 3),
]
questions_for_older = [
    ("THIS IS FIRST QUESTION", ("OPTION 1...", "OPTION 2...", "OPTION 3..."), 1),
    ("THIS IS SECOND QUESTION", ("OPTION 1...", "OPTION 2...", "OPTION 3..."), 2),
    ("THIS IS THIRD QUESTION", ("OPTION 1...", "OPTION 2...", "OPTION 3..."), 3),
]
```

With this example you could have

```
username = input("What is your name? ")
age = int(input(f"What is your age, {username}? "))

# According the age copy the questions
if age == 11:
    questions = questions_for_11_yo
elif age > 11:
    questions = questions_for_older

# Ask number of questions
nq = int(input("How many questions would you like to answer? "))
nq = min(10, nq)  # Setting max number of questions to 10

# Create score 
score = 0
nq_asked = 0

# Ask questions
for question, options, correct in questions:
    print(question)
    print("\n".join(options))
    answer = int(input("Your answer: "))
    if correct == answer:
        print("CORRECT! :)")
        score += 1  # Increase score
    else:
        print("Incorrect :(")
    nq_asked += 1
    if nq_asked == nq:
        break
print(f"You finished! Your score is {score}")
```

Like this the order of questions will always be the same, you could use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) if you want it randomized.